# Celery Flower returning 500s on Broker Stats with Redis and SSL

Tags: python, heroku, redis, celery, flower

I just installed celery flower.

It is working great for showing me real-time tasks, which queue they were processed on, cpu usage, and the processing time.

I also want to have access to the broker page so I can monitor queue lengths.

The issue I am having is with SSL.

The broker page returns a 500. Looking at the logs, I am seeing the following stack trace.

```
2020-12-24T21:19:21.828079+00:00 app[web.1]: [W 201224 21:19:21 connection:255] Secure redis scheme specified (rediss) with no ssl options, defaulting to insecure SSL behaviour.
2020-12-24T21:19:21.854471+00:00 app[web.1]: [W 201224 21:19:21 connection:255] Secure redis scheme specified (rediss) with no ssl options, defaulting to insecure SSL behaviour.
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878474+00:00 app[web.1]: [E 201224 21:19:21 web:1793] Uncaught exception GET /broker (...)
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878479+00:00 app[web.1]: HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='...herokuapp.com', method='GET', uri='/broker', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='...')
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878480+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878481+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1704, in _execute
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878481+00:00 app[web.1]: result = await result
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878482+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878482+00:00 app[web.1]: yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878482+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 162, in _fake_ctx_run
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878483+00:00 app[web.1]: return f(*args, **kw)
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878483+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flower/views/broker.py", line 31, in get
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878485+00:00 app[web.1]: http_api=http_api, broker_options=broker_options, broker_use_ssl=broker_use_ssl)
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878485+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flower/utils/broker.py", line 237, in __new__
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878486+00:00 app[web.1]: return RedisSsl(broker_url, *args, **kwargs)
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878486+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flower/utils/broker.py", line 220, in __init__
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878486+00:00 app[web.1]: super(RedisSsl, self).__init__(broker_url, *args, **kwargs)
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878487+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flower/utils/broker.py", line 134, in __init__
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878487+00:00 app[web.1]: self.redis = self._get_redis_client()
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878488+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flower/utils/broker.py", line 155, in _get_redis_client
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878488+00:00 app[web.1]: return redis.Redis(**self._get_redis_client_args())
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878489+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flower/utils/broker.py", line 225, in _get_redis_client_args
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878489+00:00 app[web.1]: client_args.update(self.broker_use_ssl)
2020-12-24T21:19:21.878554+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
2020-12-24T21:19:21.881667+00:00 app[web.1]: [W 201224 21:19:21 connection:255] Secure redis scheme specified (rediss) with no ssl options, defaulting to insecure SSL behaviour.
```

It looks like I need to pass in the cert somehow to `broker_use_ssl`, but I am not sure where or how.

This is all deployed on Heroku. The rediss URL is what's on my production application, flower is on a separate app.

On celery I have `{"ssl_cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE}`.

Flower deployed on heroku looks like

requirements.txt as follows

```
celery==4.4.4
future==0.18.2
flower==0.9.7 
redis==3.5.3
```

Then a Procfile where I try to pass in `ssl.CERT_NONE` which returns 0. It doesn't work.

```
web: flower --port=$PORT --broker=$BROKER_URL --basic_auth=$FLOWER_BASIC_AUTH --broker_use_ssl={"ssl_cert_reqs": 0}
```

Can anyone shed some light on how to setup these configuration options?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a fix related to `broker_use_ssl` was [merged](https://github.com/mher/flower/commit/028a8919577507326447c6c235d6a582209b3203) to `master` two days ago. Not sure if it only improves or bug fixes. There's a related issue [here](https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/1005). Note that the latest release doesn't contain this fix yet (released 4 days ago).

Anyway, here is things that you can try:

1. Something with the way you're passing the value of `--broker_use_ssl` - maybe you need to escape the quotes, something like: `--broker_use_ssl={\"ssl_cert_reqs\": 0}` or `--broker_use_ssl="{\"ssl_cert_reqs\": 0}"`.
2. Try to pass your settings via a [configuration file](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#configuration) instead of the command line, like: `flower --conf=celeryconfig.py` - that way you don't need to handle the escaping and you can set the value as you did (`{"ssl_cert_reqs": 0}`).
3. Use the `master` branch to see if the last commit solves your problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this, it's definitely pushed me in the right direction. Escaping the quotes was not working for me, so I tried adding the config file and I'm having issues with import errors. `celery.utils.imports.NotAPackage: Error: Module 'celeryconfig.py' doesn't exist, or it's not a valid Python module name.` Any direction there, I tried adding an __init__.py file with no luck?

Comment: @hancho did you try the full path? `/path/to/celeryconfig.py`